# extract percentages of a string

Tags: python, string, slice

I'm looking to create a python code that will identify the length of an amino acid sequence (entered as a string), as well as the the first 20% of the string, the last 20% of the string, and the middle 60% of a string.

I know I would be able to use slicing, but you have to know the exact position of the string sequence you want to extract (e.g., [0:20]-->returns string from position 1 to 20). Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can still use slice. Just figure out the length of the string first.

```
length = len(your_string)

first = your_string[:int(length*0.2)]
middle = your_string[int(length*0.2):int(length*0.8)]
last = your_string[int(length*0.8):]
```

Here's the python interpreter output:

```
>>> your_string = '1234567890'
>>> length = len(your_string)
>>> 
>>> first = your_string[:int(length*0.2)]
>>> middle = your_string[int(length*0.2):int(length*0.8)]
>>> last = your_string[int(length*0.8):]
>>> 
>>> print (first, middle, last)
('12', '345678', '90')
```

Note that the first 20% and last 20% may not be the same length in all cases. For example an input string of size 11 will have two characters for the first 20%, and three characters for the last 20%.

Comment: You need to use `middle = your_string[int(length*0.2):int(length*0.8)]`. Notice the missing "78" in your output.

Answer (score 0):

You can define all that within a function which takes the string as the argument

You can do this

```
def amino(string):
    L=len(string)
    twenty = (20 * L) / 100
    sixty  = (60 * L) / 100
    print(string[:int(twenty)])
    print(string[int(twenty):int(twenty+sixty)])
    print(string[int(twenty+sixty):])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def amino_acid_sequence(string):
    first = int(len(string) * 0.2)
    middle = int(len(string) * 0.6)
    return (string[:first], string[first:first + middle], string[first + middle:])
```

and the result of testing:

```
>>> amino_acid_sequence('1234567890')
('12', '345678', '90')
>>> amino_acid_sequence('1234567890a')
('12', '345678', '90a')
>>> amino_acid_sequence('1234567890ab')
('12', '3456789', '0ab')
```

Hope this can help you.